# How to combine Subjects and Observables with Angular rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject, subject

I have the following two subscriptions:

```
this.service1.source1.subscribe(countries => {
  this.filteredData =  [];
  countries.forEach(country => {
    this.filteredData = this.data.filter(user => {
      return user.country == country;
    });
  });
});

this.service2.source2.subscribe(companies => {
  companies.forEach(company => {
    this.filteredData =  [];
    this.filteredData = this.data.filter(user => {
      return user.company == company;
    });
  });
});
```

where source1 and source2 are `BehaviorSubject` and both events are being caught by `subscribe`.

I want to combine both subscriptions because I want to filter data depending on both results returned by `subscribe`

I tried `forkJoin` and `zip`

```
zip([this.service1.source1, this.service1.source2]).subscribe(results => {
  console.log('zip results:', results);
});

forkJoin([this.service1.source1, this.service1.source2]).subscribe(results => {
  console.log('forkJoin results:', results);
});
```

But with those (zip & forkJoin) I noticed I am not even getting anything on the console, as if `subscribe` is not getting executed when events are emitted.

How can I combine the results of both sources into one subscription?

Comment: Have you tried removing the array from `forkJoin`? It accepts a vararg of sources, but I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`forkJoin` may not be suitable for your use case because it **emits the last emitted value from each, when all observables COMPLETE.**

`zip` also may not give you the desired behavior because **It waits for all input streams to have all emitted their n-th value and as soon as this condition is met, it combines all those n-th values and emits the n-th combined value.**

so in either case you won't get an emission until there is an emission in both observables. since `this.service1.source1` and`this.service1.source2` are [BehaviorSubject](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject#behaviorsubject) using `zip` guarantees an initial emission. but later emissions will occur only when both observables emit.

i suggest to use [combineLatest](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest) beacuse **whenever any input stream emits a value, it combines the latest values emitted by each input stream.**

```js
combineLatest(this.service1.source1, this.service1.source2).subscribe(results => {
  console.log('combineLatest results:', results);
});
```

and since `this.service1.source1` and`this.service1.source2` are [BehaviorSubject](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject#behaviorsubject) such that:

> A variant of Subject that requires an initial value and emits its current value whenever it is subscribed to.

it is guaranteed that you get an emmission whenever you subscribe to it and whenever any of the observables emit a value.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax is wrong. Both [**`forkJoin`**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) and [**`zip`**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/zip) accept Observables as arguments. NOT an array of Observables. Remove `[]` from the call and you should be fine.

Try this:

```
zip(this.service1.source1, this.service1.source2).subscribe(results => {
  console.log('zip results:', results);
});

forkJoin(this.service1.source1, this.service1.source2).subscribe(results => {
  console.log('forkJoin results:', results);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As @ysf pointed out above, if you want to filter the local data with both results upon either of emission, you should go for `combineLatest`.

Additionally, I’d recommend you to create a variable in each service as an Observable instance for the `BehaviorSubject`. Like:

```
// at Service1.service.ts
export class Service1Service {
  // Do not expose Subject directly.
  private source1 = new BehaviorSubject<YourDataType[]>(YourInitialValue);
  private source2 = new BehaviorSubject<YourDataType[]>(YourInitialValue);

  source1$: Observable<YourDataType[]>;
  source2$: Observable<YourDataType[]>;

  constructor() {
    // Create an Observable instance for your sake and open it to the public.
    this.source1$ = this.source1.asObservable();
    this.source2$ = this.source2.asObservable();
  }
}


// at wherever you subscribe
combineLatest(this.service1.source1$, this.service1.source2$).pipe(
  filter(([res1, res2]: YourDataType[]) => {
    // Filter your data with res1, res2
  })
).subscribe();
```